# Is it possible to determine the square root of a sum of matrix products?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am considering the following set of equations:

$$
\mathbf{L}^\text{T}\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{A} +\mathbf{B}^\text{T}\mathbf{B}
$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are non-square matrices ($n\times m$) and are known. I want to determine $\mathbf{L}$. Now I could work out $\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}^\text{T}\mathbf{B}$ which would give me two square $m\times m$ matrices. And Cholesky decompose their sum. However I wouldn't then retrieve an $n\times m$ matrix and instead get an $m\times m$ matrix.

Now clearly if I could take the square root of this system then I can find $L$

$$
\sqrt{\mathbf{L}^\text{T}\mathbf{L}} = \mathbf{L}^\text{T} = \sqrt{\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{A} +\mathbf{B}^\text{T}\mathbf{B}}
$$
Is this possible? I suspect not but I though it best to ask in case there is something I've not thought about. So to reiterate, what I'm looking for is the $n\times m$ solution for $\mathbf{L}$.

Comment: If $n < m$, then this is not necessarily possible

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you're asking (forgetting all the unnecessary details) is this: Let $M$ be a known $m\times m$ *symmetric* matrix and $L$ a $n\times m$ unknown matrix. Can we *uniquely* solve the equation
$$
L^TL=M
$$
Well let me explain this with the example of $n=1$ and $m=2$. Let $L=(x,y)$. Then your question boils down to solving
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x^2 & xy\\
xy & y^2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
b & c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
as you can see, this might not be possible in the general case. This is because $x^2=a$ yields $x=\pm \sqrt{a}$ and $y^2=c$ yields $y=\pm \sqrt{c}$, but unless $b=\pm \sqrt{ac}$, we are in trouble. Even then there are always two solutions (due to the signs).

But you may say in my example $M$ is more special than just a symmetric matrix. So let's consider another example. Let $A=(a,b)$ and $B=(c,d)$ and $M=A^TA+B^TB$. Then you want to solve
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x^2 & xy\\
xy & y^2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a^2+c^2 & ab+cd\\
ab+cd & b^2+d^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
you see there is the same issue encountered here: Unless $ab+cd=\pm \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}$ there is no solution. The problem persists to the general $n\times m$ matrices with $n<m$.

Comment: If $L$ is a solution, so is $UL$ where $U$ is any $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix.  On the other hand, $L^T L$ has rank at most $n$, so there are no solutions if $A^T A + B^T B$ has rank  $> n$, which it typically does if $m > n$.